# Display thumbnail image over iframe embedded youtube video

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, reactstrap

I want to display an image as thumbnail and when you click on it the youtube video should play. I tried using the `<video>` tag but it does not support youtube videos hence couldn't set the image. I want to implement this in Reactjs. Can anyone suggest any solution to this?

```
<iframe
     width='100%'
     height='100%'
     src=[youtube_video_link]
     frameBorder='0'
     allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
     allowFullScreen
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use `reactplayer` package in your app to show any video with thumbnail.
Here it's available: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)

Basic example:

```
<ReactPlayer                                                    
 className=[any_class_name]
 light={true}
 url={url}
 playing
/>
```

the `light` prop attaches video thumbnail to the video.

You may also set the thumbnail as any other image(of your choice) by simply replacing true with  any image URL.

Comment: I tried to use light = my_custom_image_url but it is not working